# pinMode PWM: Unable to do this when using /dev/gpiomem. Try sudo?

Tags: ros, ros2, raspberry-pi, pwm

I have been scouring the web for a few hours now and I cannot seem to fix the problem. I am using RPi 4B 8GB RAM with Ubuntu 22.04 server.

When trying to run C++ code with wiringPi to activate PWM I get this error

```
pinMode PWM: Unable to do this when using /dev/gpiomem. Try sudo?
```

I am running my executable through ROS2 and hence cannot give it root privileges. I have already tried:

- `sudo adduser pi gpio`
- `sudo usermod -a -G gpio $USER`
- `sudo chown root.gpio /dev/gpiomem`
- `sudo chmod g+rw /dev/gpiomem`

and none will do.

Also the output of my `ls -l` is

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 506, 0 Feb 19 21:48 /dev/gpiomem
```